# Capybara + Selenium fill_in skipping spaces?

Tags: testing, selenium, capybara

Has anyone seen this problem with selenium & capybara where `fill_in 'Description:', with: "foo bar baz"` but when you look at the field, it's actual value is: "foobarbaz"?

For example:

```
(rdb:1) fill_in 'Description:', :with => "   d    "
""
(rdb:1) find(:field, 'Description:').value
"d"
```

But if I wait long enough in the debugger (sometimes 30 seconds, sometimes a couple of minutes), it just starts working properly all on its own??

Is this a known bug in (old versions of) selenium or capybara possibly?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: @JasonSwett lol nope. I have a loop that tests the value of the field to ensure it matches what I set it to, and resets it using `fill_in` if it doesn't match. Sorry :(